# Camelcase class names for models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is it possible to have a model whose name consists of more than one word e.g. UserProfile and use it in OneToMany relationships with User, for instance, User.hasMany(UserProfile). 
Currently, i suspect that either i have not set up correctly something in models or it just is not working like that @ this moment. Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kristaps_petersons/y75eQ/17/.

Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to snake case the relationShip ids in your fixtures, and I think this will work.
The second thing is to define an id for the users.
In fact, the structures defined in the fixtures must be like the JSON you will receive from the server.

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/y75eQ/19/